# Update Amplify datastore from AWS lambda function

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, datastore

In my application, there is functionality that when we upload files in s3 then related AWS Lambda trigger is invoked. When Lambda function trigger I want to store file related data in AWS Amplify data store. Is this possible to access AWS Amplify data store in Lambda function? Any references?

[s3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) ---> [Lambda function trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) ---> [Amplify Datastore](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started/q/platform/js/)

Note: I found that we can add data from Lambda function to DynamoDB, but my app is using in AWS Amplify data store.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Perform a GraphQL mutation using code like this: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/how-it-works/q/platform/js/#writing-data-from-the-appsync-console

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API feature of Amplify to enable access to features like DataStore. Take a look at [this reference](https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/functions/graphql-from-lambda/q/platform/js/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference for Amplify. Amplify data store uses Dynamodb. So you would need to grant IAM policy to your lambda function to have access to the db. read [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-create-an-aws-iam-policy-to-grant-aws-lambda-access-to-an-amazon-dynamodb-table/) reference

Comment: Yes, it's true, but you have to also address fields that are not visible from amplify console e.g. _lastChangedAt, _version, and _deleted as pointed out in a link given by @Richard [Writing data to appsync](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/how-it-works/q/platform/js/#writing-data-from-the-appsync-console)