# AWS: Store file data in AWS Amplify data store

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, datastore

In my application, there is functionality that when we upload files in s3 then related AWS Lambda trigger is invoked. When Lambda function trigger I want to store file related data in AWS Amplify data store. Is this possible to access AWS Amplify data store in Lambda function? Any references?

s3 ---> Lambda function trigger ---> Amplify Datastore

Note: I found that we can add data from Lambda function to DynamoDB, but my app is using in AWS Amplify data store.

[Update Amplify datastore from AWS lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69268265/update-amplify-datastore-from-aws-lambda-function)

Thank you in advance